# Iterate over dictionary items with classes as keys in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

An object I'm passing to a template has a method called `active_children` that returns an `OrderedDict` whose keys are Python classes (Django models, to be exact) and values QuerySets of those models with certain filters applied.

I have something like the following in the template:

```
{% for cls, objs in object.active_children.items %}
    {{ cls }}
    {% for obj in objs %}
        {{ obj }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This returns the error `Error during template rendering. coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found` at the line with `{{ cls }}`.

However, if I change all that to this:

```
{{ object.active_children.items }}
```

Then I don't get an error and see the output `[(<class 'app.MyModel'>, [<MyModel:1>, <MyModel:2>, <MyModel:3>]), (<class 'app.AnotherModel'>, [])]` on the page. Proving that the class key indeed wasn't None.

I also don't get an error if I remove the `{{ cls }}` line from the first example. Then all the objects in the QuerySet are properly printed.

Is there a way I could still use classes as dictionary keys in Django templates?

I'm using Django 1.4.5 / Python 2.7.3.

Comment: It seems the error prone class doesn't have a `__unicode__` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#models)

Comment: I'm not sure about that and if this is what you need, however you can try with:

`{{ cls|default_if_none:"" }}`

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide Thanks, but how would that help? `unicode(Klass)` should always return a unicode string, even if the class doesn't define it. Does Django specifically look for the `__unicode__` attribute? Though, I just tested this by adding a `__unicode__` method to all classes, and still got the same error. :-/

Comment: What's your output for: `from ... import YourClass; print YourClass; unicode(YourClass);` on shell?

Comment: I get the same output as when I had `{{ object.active_children.items }}` in the template, i.e. `<class 'app.MyModel'>`. Note that this happens whether or not `__unicode__` is defined. You can try it yourself on a dummy class: `class Test(object): pass`, `print Test, unicode(Test), str(Test)`: all 3 return the same thing.

Comment: I have tried your code. The only way I can reproduce your error is by setting an empty return on the class's unicode method or None. Please add your relevant code to check for any oddities.

Answer (score 0):

The django template engine cannot coerce your class to unicode that's why a `__unicode__` or `__str__` method is required, e.g.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    attr = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.attr)  # instead of None
```

Comment: See my comment on the question. Also, isn't `__unicode__` called on instances (hence the `self` arg), not on class objects?

Comment: @imiric `__unicode__` is called on whatever object is passed to it, but when you use `{{ cls }}` the object is the class itself, not an instance of the class.